# sqlite3 can not open database file when path is given by an environment variable

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database from which I need to dump a few tables. I created a small script:

```
$ cat dump.cmd
.output ./layers.sql
.dump layers
.output ./attributes.sql
.dump attributes
.exit
```

The database file is owned by the user and accessible to `sqlite3`:

```
$ ls -laht /home/user/temp/sqlite.db
-rw-r--r--+ 1 user super-users 2,7G 25 jul 10:52 /home/user/temp/sqlite.db

$ sqlite3 /home/user/temp/sqlite.db
SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

The exact location of the database is only known at run time, so the path must be read from an environment variable. This is where things are going wrong:

```
$ DB_PATH=/home/user/temp/sqlite.db
$ sqlite3 $DB_PATH < dump.cmd
Error: unable to open database "/home/user/temp/sqlite.db": unable to open database file
```

I tried in a different way with `eval` but there is the same error:

```
$ CMD="sqlite3 "$DB_PATH" < dump.cmd"
$ eval `$CMD`
Error: unable to open database "/home/user/temp/sqlite.db": unable to open database file
```

How can `sqlite3` be started with a path from an environment variable?

Comment: *sqlite3 /home/user/temp/sqlite.db* In this case, can you execute any statements or do you get the same error when you try?

Comment: If I use the explicit path everything works as expect. Only fails if the path is passed through an environment variable.

Comment: Random selects or those .dumps work? You need to test something that actually reads from the database. And if that works,  are you using the same user for all these different versions?

Comment: The first code block includes the code at play. It works fine with the path passed explicitly. Some user in all tests.